# Adicionar apenas um produto no carrinho Woocommerce ou limpar carrinho

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

Olá, estou fazendo um clube de assinaturas utilizando o WooCommerce e gostaria que fosse possível comprar apenas um produto por vez. Pensei em talvez limpar o carrinho antes de adicionar o novo produto ou mesmo limitar a quantidade de produtos.

Alguém sabe se é possível?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para limpar o carrinho antes de adicionar um novo produto, você pode usar o seguinte filtro:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart' );

function woo_custom_add_to_cart( $cart_item_data ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

    // Do nothing with the data and return
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

[Nessa thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363268/need-woocommerce-to-only-allow-1-product-in-the-cart-if-a-product-is-already-in) do SOen (que foi de onde tirei o snippet acima) você pode acompanhar uma discussão um pouco mais aprofundada sobre como realizar esse processo, e também como limitar o número de itens do carrinho a apenas 1 (o que, na prática, é a mesma coisa).

Comment: Funcionou Caio, muito obrigado.

Comment: @RonaldoThomaz, se a resposta lhe foi útil, não esqueça de marcá-la como correta. Aproveitando, como você é novo por aqui, sugiro que faça o [tour].